# How to send large video like a normal one with telebot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I have my own bot for downloading videos from TikTok, but due to Telegram restrictions on video size, videos that weigh more than 20MB look very strange when sent [screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLBF5.jpg)

Here is the code I use to send videos that are less than 20mb:

```
bot.send_video(chat_id, video_url)
```

And here is how I send videos that are more than 20mb:

```
video_file = requests.get(video_url)
bot.send_video(chat_id, video_file.content)
```

Is there a way to send a video larger than 20MB with normal video time instead of 0:00 and preview?